# How to decode Simulator path to application Document folder on disc?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm curious what those 'a' and 'b' strings means in path to simulator app Documents folder (see attachment) on my disc?:

[image]

I supposed that 'a' was simulator UUID, but after performing in runtime this code:

```
let uuid = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString
```

I realized that nor 'a' and 'b' parts of this string are not my simulator UUIDs.

Maybe someone can tell me what those IDs in path for application Document folder means? 
There is any way to obtain those 'a' and 'b' values in app runtime on simulator?

---

Code snipped which I used to generate URL on my attachment png:

```
let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part "a" is just a UUID representing the simulator instance (iPhone 6s+ for iOS 10.0, for example).

Part "b" is just a UUID representing your app's sandbox. It may change every time you build and run your app.

Neither id has anything to do with any UUID you can get in code. You can only get the whole path using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused because 'identifierForVendor' returned value doesn't match to any of IDs from this url, now I realize that 'identifierForVendor' value is not UDID at all.